# Accessing variables through classes

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

So lets say I have a core program class which instantiates a `Page` object.

This `Page` object has a property `$id` (which is the page id of the page we're currently on).

In the `Page` class it looks in the database and it sets up the template for the page by instantiating a `Template` object.

In this `Template` object I want to put in a content block. This is handled by a `Content` class which I isntantiate in the `Template` class.

Now for this content to work properly I need to be able to get the `$id` from the `Page` object owned by the program core. Is there any way to do this? It seems rather fiddly to pass through the page id, especially as when it gets to it there could be 10s of layers between classes?

If I make the $id variable static (`static $id;`) then can I get it again using `Page::$id` instead of having to access the actual instance of the object that I set it in?

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is often handled by "[dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)".  It's quite common to pass in an object like your `Page` object at creation of the `Template` object, in the Template constructor.  The Page object itself may be a property of Template, or only its $id property.  So it isn't necessary to pass in the id on every function call.

`Template::__construct($Page)`

If the Template class is related the Page class, it may also extend the Page class, whereby it would already have access to the `Page::$id` if that property was `protected` or `public`.

Comment: The best PHP DI library is Symfony's http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/

Comment: ah, you see Template is part of a Page so its not really related in this respect. So, its a case of just passing the $page object through the constructors till I need to use it? Hypothetically (at the moment) what happens if in the core I make a few objects, lets say a User object which handles sessions and permissions and the Page object mentioned above. Then, to use part of the user object you're saying I have to pass my $user object into my Page class then pass in my $user object and my $page object to every other class I make until I want to use it somewhere down the line?

Comment: What happens with hugely complex programs? Where you may have 10, 20, 100s, 1000s of different objects all which need to share properties and methods but are independent of each other? Isn't it going to get quite complicated keeping track of all the dependency injections?

Comment: Generally speaking, if an object will be needed again and again in another class, I would pass it in the constructor so it's always available.  But if it will only be required by one or two methods, I would pass it as a parameter only to those methods.  If you expect to have 100s or 1000s of such dependencies, then you need to do very careful architectural planning, extending classes where necessary.  You don't want to end up like http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Enterprise-Dependency-Big-Ball-of-Yarn.aspx

Comment: But it's not uncommon for many or most classes in a project to need access to one or two.  If lots of them require both the Page and User classes, I would just pass both of them in the constructors of all the classes that need them. You needn't worry then about passing them in chains.